# How to retain values from ascx control from aspx page, button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

IDE: VS 2012 web

I am having a test.aspx page and the user control is added dynamically on this page using following code

```
 internal static List<ucTest> collTest  = null;
 private void PageLoad()  
 {
      //called in page on load, handled properly across postback.
      collTest   = new List<ucTest>();
 }


    private void AddTestControl()
    {

            ucTest obj= LoadControl("~/UserControl/ucTest.ascx") as ucTest;
            collTest.Add(obj); //control instance is added in list, to retrieve back values.
    }
```

Now on buttonSave Click which is in test.aspx code behind file, I am trying to fetch back the  ucTest textbox value., which I am getting empty.  can you tell me how to retain this value.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucTest test = (ucTest )this.FindControl("ucTest.ascx"); //not working, test is null.  




        foreach (ucTest objTest in collTest)
        {


           string s  = objTest.txtSomthing.value; //here s is showing empty.., even the value is populated in form.; , txtSomthing is public in designer.
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to retrieve these values from ucTest., the aspx page can contain multiple ucTest controls.

Comment: Where are you calling `AddTestControl()`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're adding this usercontrol dynamically? Also, why you're adding the usercontrol to the list? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The control is added when drop down value changes  such as 1, 2 ,3 ,4 etc , everything is perfect, I need to know  how to retrieve back the values.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a textbox called txtName in your userControl, then I'll expose it value by adding a property in the code behind of the usercontrol. ie.

```
public string FirstName
{
   get
   {
      return txtName.Text;
    }
    set
    {
       txtName.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Then in your aspx you do the following:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucTest test = (ucTest )collTest[yourdropdown.SelectedIndex];
    string strName = ucTest.FirstName;
}
```

Comment: This should work, but this is not working, Same this I am trying and asked in question.

Comment: Is there controls in collTest?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved using following way:

```
string value = Request.From["someDynamicID"];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add the control the parent page, This is Key, you must do the load from the Page_Init() method.  This way it will get added to the viewstate of the site. If you add it in Page_Load() for example you will not be able to get the values of the user control in the Save() method.

[This link has an example with source in a ZIP file.](http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/Dynamically-Adding-User-Controls-to-an-ASPX-page)